# how to create an web api for login /signup with google and facebook

Tags: json, codeigniter

Does anyone know that how to create a web-services to login and register with facebook and google ?

-thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer this official links  [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) ,  [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Comment: HybridAuth is a good start. Mix it with Ion Auth and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter this is where you will find all the info you need. [Codeigniter Facebook](https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter).
You will also need Facebook PHP SDK wich can be found here [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) , and you also have to create an app in you facebook developer's account [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com). Next you have to place in your libraries folder folder the SDK from facebook and the library mentioned above and in config folder the facebook config where you will have to enter your app's id and secret received from [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com).Also don't forget to

> require_once FCPATH.'/application/libraries/Facebook/autoload.php';

in the Facebook library.Then you should be able to use it just like in the example from [Codeigniter Facebook](https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter).